# My program throws an exception when encountering very high numbers

Tags: java

So my problem is that when I write in my 4 numbers and they are something like `987579739 90273946 38403649 34839204739374839`, then I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "34839204739374839"
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2123)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at linetest2.main(linetest2.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Here is my program:

```
public class linetest {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        java.util.Scanner tastatur = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        int a, x, b, y;
        a = tastatur.nextInt();
        x = tastatur.nextInt();
        b = tastatur.nextInt();
        y = tastatur.nextInt();

        if (a * x + b == y)
            System.out.println("LINJE");
        else if (a * x + b > y)
            System.out.println("UNDER");
        else
            System.out.println("OVER");
    }
}
```

What can I do to allow it to read these high numbers? Any suggestion would be appreciated :).

Comment: read it as string and use BigInteger/long class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assigning a big number to `int`, Integer numbers cannot hold this big value.

You may want to use `long` instead of `int`, along side with using `nextLong()` instead of using `nextInt()`

Comment: so i did as you said and made this: public class linetest {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        java.util.Scanner tastatur = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        long a, x, b, y;
        a = tastatur.nextLong();
        x = tastatur.nextLong();
        b = tastatur.nextLong();
        y = tastatur.nextLong();

        if (a * x + b == y) System.out.println("LINJE");
        else if (a * x + b > y) System.out.println("UNDER");
        else System.out.println("OVER");
    }
}

Comment: I will but i need to wait 3 minutes to do so

Answer (score 0):

`34839204739374839` is too big for `nextInt()`, but `nextLong()` should be able to read it. Of course you'll have to store the output of `nextLong()` in a `long` variable.

```
    long a, x, b, y;
    a = tastatur.nextLong();
    x = tastatur.nextLong();
    b = tastatur.nextLong();
    y = tastatur.nextLong();
```

This will allow you to use bigger numbers, but `long` has its limits too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways:

- Read it as long as your number is out of range of integer which i would prefer.
- Read it as String and convert it into BigInteger if its even bigger.

Something you could do like to convert a string to BigInteger:

```
String d = tastatur.next();
BigInteger b = new BigInteger(d);
```

Or even reading it as long

```
long d = tastatur.nextLong();
```